# How to expand search bar and hide other elements at same time?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to make a search bar along with a header in one line. When I focus on the search bar I want it to expand full width and hide the header. I can expand the search bar but can't hide the header. I don't know what's wrong. Here's the code

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>
          .header, div, .search{
              display: inline;
           }
          .search{
             width: 150px; 
             transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
             -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
          }
          .search:focus{
             width: 100%;
          }
          .search:focus .header{
             display: none;
          }
      </style>


</head>


<body>


<h1 class="header">myWebsite</h1>


<div>
     <input type="text" class="search" name="search" placeholder="search...">
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

So please help me out.

Comment: The answer lies in JavaScript. It seems only css can't achieve it. I use show() on onblur and hide() on onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the header will hide when submiting the input:

```
 <! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>
          .header, div, .search{
              display: inline;
           }
          .search{
             width: 150px; 
             transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
             -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
          }
          .search:focus{
             width: 100%;
          }
          .search:focus .header{
             display: none;
          }
      </style>


</head>


<body>


<h1 id="header">myWebsite</h1>


<div>
     <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="search..." onchange="hide()">
  </div>


</body>
<script>
function hide() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: CSS doesn't provide eventing, so adding an onchange event  or key event would be impossible, javascript is the only way to do it. I see you're starting to learn, I suggest you to start learning jQuery, it's has a very light API and it's great for begginers ;)

Comment: No no I am not starting to learn :) Have been developing for many years - just FYI. I know there's no such solution in CSS but I think JS solution wasn't the target...

Comment: Thanks I will try this one

Comment: I updated it, basically I can't to anymore with pure CSS, even if I want. That's the most vanilla way to hide an element on input change..

Comment: Yes, CSS doesn't give such possiblity (yet i hope!) so we must employ JS